# Laravel 5.8 : Email verification link leads to a 403 error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the latest version of Laravel (normally) and tried to implement the authentication with email verification. However, the link in the email I receive after an user registration leads to an 403 error page. The link seems correct though.

I'm working in 'localhost' with Homestead and Vagrant.
Registering a user is working, I get the created user at the end of my function, and the database is well populated.

I had to edit the RegisterController create method because the mail was not being sent.

First, when clicking the link, I only had a blank page. After some reading, I learned that the user needed to be authenticated before being verified, and that my RegisterController after registering the user was not authenticating him.
I added some code to authenticate the user after his creation.
Now, when clicking the link, I get a 403 error page.

Note : My table that is not the default table contains the email_verified_at field.

Here is my create method inside the RegisterController :

```php
protected function create(Request $request)
    {
        //Create user in database
        $user = User::create([
            'Username' => $request['pc2f448466c4bad46f466f025e6cf88f9'],
            'email' => $request['p07d5d4eb055cc69dbba790bb9d39a3dc'],
            'Password' => md5($request['pb80ee032d334d60f5bc555af500fcf87']),
            'SecretQuestion' => $request['secret_question'],
            'SecretAnswer' => $request['secret_answer'],
            'Nickname' => $request['p9c969905e63e2824c45b8712e6d29585']
        ]);

        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();


        Auth::login($user);
    }
```

Here is my VerificationController :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Email Verification Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling email verification for any
    | user that recently registered with the application. Emails may also
    | be re-sent if the user didn't receive the original email message.
    |
    */

    use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return route('home');
    }
}
```

I tried setting `protected $proxies = '*';` in TrustProxies middleware.

My app constants in the .env file :

```
APP_NAME=Furya
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

In my web routing file, my first route is :

```php
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('main/home');
})->name('home');
```

When using `php artisan route:list` I see the right middlewares for the `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` route.

In my users table (MySQL), the field `email_verified_at` has a datetime type.

In the app config, my application URL is set this way :

```php
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://sunshine.local'),

'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),
```

The link I actually receive looks like this : `http://sunshine.local/email/verify/177?expires=1567179404&signature=0a81e1370934c95282975c9fb7cfa379fd1945814e45894ffec5728e04ad4f7a`

I don't know what is happening, and sadly no solutions found on the internet helped me until now.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have the controller `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/VerificationController.php`? If so, can you include it in your question?

Comment: @UdoE. Yes I have it, and didn't edited it. I'm editing my post with its code.

Comment: Ok. After you follow the verification link,  does your user get verified? I mean, when you check the `email_verified_at` field in the user table, is it `null` or is updated (even with the 403 error)?  Also, can you provide your home route definition in `web.php`. It seems the url `'/'` is protected somehow and must be accessed through the defined route method.

Comment: @UdoE. The field remains null. I update my post with my home route definition.

Comment: @TomGiru see my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I see protected `protected $proxies = '*'`. Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: @UdoE. No, it's only a solution I tried from another post. I'm just using this website in a local setup with Vagrant and Homestead.

Comment: I know its an old one! But if someone comes across here like me, thought it might help. The main problem seems to be the cache! and compiled routes and views. After searching for solutions everywhere about what I did wrong. Just ran the following commands: `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`  followed by `php artisan route:clear` and lastly `php artisan view:clear`. Restarted my server and Voila!  it started working.

Answer (score 0):

From your `web.php` file, when making http web requests, your application root url `'/'` can only be accessed through the named route: `route('home')` which returns a custom view.

So, include a `redirectTo()` method in `VerificationController.php` like this

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
// other imports

class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return route('home');
    }
}
```

Now you should be redirected to a **valid** route after email verification.

Comment: Sadly, I still get a 403 error page after clicking the link.

Comment: Re-registered a new user and check the new link again. Plus, you included only part of your `VerificationController`. Include the whole

Comment: I edit my post, and here's the link I get : 
http://sunshine.local/email/verify/181?expires=1567284855&signature=274a84c07effa614760b1760f3f71100078ea5aa37650e7d772a7ac7926ba6cf

Comment: Try clearing your route and application caches and refreshing auto-load by running these commands on your console in order  `php artisan route:cache` ,  `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump auto-load`.  re-register and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried but it's still not working. Note that I was unable to perform `php artisan route:cache` because my routes use closures.

Comment: sorry use these `php artisan route:clear` and this `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`
```

I Noticed you have a backtick in your route. Just after the verify route semi colon. Try removing that and see what happens

Comment: Only a copy-pasting mistake. I don't have it in my routing file.

Comment: @TomGirou Ok, have you checked the log files. 403 means forbidden request. It means you are not allowed to see that resource. Please verify that the user is logged in. Paste the errors logged

Answer (score 0):

It was due to a problem about the name of a field in the users table.

See my other post for the answer : [Laravel 5.8 : Remember me token not being saved in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768735/laravel-5-8-remember-me-token-not-being-saved-in-database)

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue;
Check in your .env that your

`APP_URL=http://...`

is correct and is matching up.