# Laravel 5.8 : Remember me token not being saved in database

Tags: php, laravel, token, remember-me

The token is created as a cookie, I can see it in my browser, but it's not being saved in the database.

Here is my User model :

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'accounts';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'Username', 'email', 'Password', 'Nickname', 'SecretQuestion', 'SecretAnswer', 
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'Password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

My login method in my LoginController :

```php
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('Username', $request->Username)
                    ->where('Password', md5($request->password))
                    ->first();
        if (is_null($user)) return back()->with('error', 'Votre identifiant ou mot de passe est incorrect.');
        Auth::login($user, $request->remember == 'on' ? true : false);
        if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
    }
```

When I check or not the remember_me option, it uses the Auth::login() method accordingly, with true or false argument.
However, in my database, the field is never set, although I can see a token in my browser `remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d`.

The field in my db : 
`remember_token    varchar(100)      null,`

Comment: Why are you `md5`ing the password? You've made a secure login insecure.

Comment: The application for which I develop the website use a md5 authentication. I do not have the choice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer while searching for another problem.

It was due to my id field in my accounts table not being named 'id' in lowercase.
My field was 'Id'. (Not my choice, I know it's bad).

To fix it, I had to add : `protected $primaryKey = 'Id';` to my User model.